# lua: why can't I use the name of the package?

Tags: lua

Based on [SimpleLuaClasses](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses) I've done a class in a file:

```
require 'class'

Session = class(function(self)
    self.session_name = "l_sid"
end)

function Session:init(r)
    self.session_id = r:getcookie(self.session_name)
    if not self.session_id then
        self.session_id = r:sha1(tostring(r.log_id) .. r.clock())
        r:setcookie({
            key =   self.session_name,
            value = self.session_id
        })
    end
end;
```

Now I'm trying this:

```
local session = require 'session'

function handle(r)
    local s = Session()
    s:init(r)
end
```

The previous code works. If I try `local s = session.Session()` it doesn't work.

When I try this, I get this error:`attempt to index upvalue 'session' (a boolean value)`.

Why?

Comment: As always, you should say what error you are getting instead of just saying that something "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that works:

```
--[[
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Classe Session
]]--
require 'class'

local session = {}

session.Session = class(function(self)
    self.session_name = "l_sid"
end)

function session.Session:init(r)
    self.session_id = r:getcookie(self.session_name)
    if not self.session_id then
        self.session_id = r:sha1(tostring(r.log_id) .. r.clock())
        r:setcookie({
            key =   self.session_name,
            value = self.session_id
        })
    end
end;

return session
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of the `require` function is the value returned from your module. For example, if you create a file "foo.lua" with the following contents

```
-- This is foo.lua
return 17
```

When you do in another file

```
local x = require 'foo'
print(x)
```

Its going to print 17.

In your case, in order to have `session.Session` work you would need to return a table with a `Session` field from "session.lua"

```
return { Session = Session }
```

Alternatively, you can also just return `Session` directly if you aren't returning anything else

```
-- in session.lua
return Session

-- in the other file
local Session = require 'session'
```

Finally, the reason your first sollution is working is that you are defining Session as a global variable, that is seen from every module. I would recommennt avoiding globals as much as possible so you can turn Session into a local in session.lua

```
local Session = class(function() ... end)
```

Compiling everything together, here is how your fiull session.lua file should look like

```
require 'class'

local Session = class(function(self)
    self.session_name = "l_sid"
end)

function Session:init(r)
    self.session_id = r:getcookie(self.session_name)
    if not self.session_id then
        self.session_id = r:sha1(tostring(r.log_id) .. r.clock())
        r:setcookie({
            key =   self.session_name,
            value = self.session_id
        })
    end
end;

return Session
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've found another solution which uses `session.Session()` and is package-oriented, close to yours. May I ask  you if I can add it to your response, and check your response as valid?

Comment: If its just changing `return Session` to `return {Session = Session}` then go ahead. Otherwise, I think it might be different enough for a separate answer

Comment: Ok checkout my version, which is heavily based on `LUA programming third edition`